# to create a cloudwatch-event to monitor the change in state of all EC2 instances in a specific region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a cloudwatch event to monitor the change in the state of all the EC2 instances in a specific region. This should work for both existing as well as for new instances.

If not via cloudwatch, can we create a cloudformation template or Boto3 script for the same?

Comment: Is this just for auditing purposes? If so, have a look at cloudtrail

Comment: no, this is for some other functionality where I have to trigger another function, but stuck at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below event pattern for state change off all resources

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ]
}
```

Comment: not sure about the same, is this to be added in every ec2 instance template?

Comment: no. this is a cloudwatch event rule.
you can add it like this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html

if you are not aware of cloudwatch event rules, please refer to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html

you can add targets to this rule which can be a notification or a lambda.

Comment: thanxs, this works, I added my lambda function as the target.

Comment: It is always a good practice to accept the answers that work for you.
It also helps reducing the duplicates.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers